# setting the pivot point of a rotating door in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Important: I know I can create an empty gameobject, take the door as a child of it and rotate this pivot point. But I want to do it by code.**

so I have a rotatable door in Unity. I create a pivotpoint by code and try to rotate it. The door rotates relative to its parent.

```
[SerializeField]
private Vector3 targetRotation; // rotation angles

[SerializeField]
private float duration; // rotation speed

[SerializeField]
private bool closeAgain; // close the door again?

[SerializeField]
private float waitInterval; // close the door after x seconds

private Vector3 defaultRotation; // store the rotation when starting the game
private bool isActive = false;

Transform doorPivot; // the pivot point to rotate around

private void Start()
{
    doorPivot = new GameObject().transform; // create pivot
    transform.SetParent(doorPivot); // make the door being a child of the pivot
    defaultRotation = doorPivot.eulerAngles;
}

private IEnumerator DoorRotation()
{
    if (isActive)
        yield break;

    isActive = true;

    yield return StartCoroutine(RotateDoor(doorPivot.eulerAngles + targetRotation)); // open the door

    if (!closeAgain)
        Destroy(this); // destroy the script if the door should stay open

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitInterval); // wait before closing

    yield return StartCoroutine(RotateDoor(defaultRotation)); // close the door

    isActive = false;
}

private IEnumerator RotateDoor(Vector3 newRotation) // door rotation
{
    float counter = 0;
    Vector3 defaultAngles = doorPivot.eulerAngles;
    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        doorPivot.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(defaultAngles, newRotation, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}

public void Interact() // start the rotation
{
    StartCoroutine(DoorRotation());
}
```

When starting the game, I call the method `Interact()` and the door starts rotating.

The pivot point gets created at (0,0,0) so when placing the door closer to this point, the rotation gets better. If the door is far away, the rotation is a big circle.

So I thought about placing the pivot always close to the door. But then the door gets moved away because it's a child of the pivot.

I would create a new field for the inspector

```
[SerializeField]
Vector3 pivotPosition; // position of the pivotpoint
```

and this field should represent the pivot position relative to the door.

For example

[image]

The user can choose on his own where to place the pivot point but when placing it, the door should not get moved away.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Move the pivot to the door before making it a child of it.

Comment: true story ... ok I'll leave this post here

Answer (score 0):

@Chuck Savage fixed this problem

```
   [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 pivotPosition;

    private Vector3 defaultRotation;

    Transform doorPivot;

    private void Start()
    {
        doorPivot = new GameObject().transform;
        doorPivot.position = pivotPosition; // place the pivot before parenting!
        transform.SetParent(doorPivot);
        defaultRotation = doorPivot.eulerAngles;
    }
```

Just set the pivots position before starting the parenting.